# one form data submit after new form open in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want help for form submit

**Problem :**  when one form submit after new form open and i need also few data of first form data in second form how i can do this

```
$courseData['COURSE_ID']=$this->input->get_post( 'COURSE_ID');
$courseData['COURSE_NAME']=$this->input->get_post( 'COURSE_NAME');
$this->data['new_content']=$this->load->view('admin/unit/index',$courseData,true);
```

this code is try  COURSE_ID and COURSE_NAME need in second form so what can i do ??

Comment: if you are using traditional http request then write controller for filling the fields and  if ajax is used then use javascript to fetch that fields values from prev forms

Comment: Ok first form field generate dynamic

Comment: i donot used ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flashdata, which is a part of the session library of codeigniter.

Flashdatas are session that is only kept for the next request. So the idea is to submit the form, keep the values you want in the flash data, then use it.

How flash data works:
1. Set flashdata
2. The flash data is available for the next refresh/request
3. It is now gone.

your code should be

```
function post_form()
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('session_name', $this->input->post('name');
    //Your other codes
}
```

To access the flast data, simply use the code

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('session_name'); ?>
```

You can read more about flashdatas in the user guide.

**Goodluck meyt**